# In angular, is there a way to test if a mat-error exists in a .spec test?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

In Angular, is there a way to test is a mat-error exists in a spec test? This is what I think should work, but doesn't.

```
describe('email control set to invalid email', () => {
      it('should result in email warning', () => {
        component.form.get('email').setValue('flo.com');
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(de.queryAll(By.css('#email-warning')).length).toBe(1);
      });
describe('email control set to invalid email', () => {
      it('should result in email warning', () => {
        component.form.get('email').setValue('flo@gmail.com');
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(de.queryAll(By.css('#email-warning')).length).toBe(0);
      });
```

The problem is that whether the input value is invalid, flo.com, or valid, flo@gmail.com, the length of the query array is always one. If I delete the ... from the .html, then the length of the array is zero.

I will have other  elements in my template, so I'm looking for this one in particular.

Here's my html.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input  name="email"
    formControlName="email"
    matInput
    type="email"
    placeholder="Email"
    autocomplete="off"/>
    <mat-error id="email-warning">Enter a valid email address.</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Here's my component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      pwGroup: this.fb.group({
        password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
        pwConfirmation: ['', ]
      }, {validator: this.checkPasswords})
  });
  }
```

In the browser, it works correctly, only showing the warning when the email is invalid. In fact when the email is valid, the #email-warning element doesn't exist in the inspected html. That is why I believe the length of the array should be 0.
I already know how to test it in protractor, e2e test, really just asking about .spec tests.

EDIT
Here is the inspected html when there is an error:

```
<div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c109-0" ng-reflect-ng-switch="error">

    <div class="ng-tns-c109-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);">

        <mat-error _ngcontent-uiy-c122="" role="alert" id="email-warning" class="mat-error ng-tns-c109-0" ng-reflect-id="email-warning">Enter a valid email address.</mat-error>

    </div><!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "error"}--><!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "hint"}-->

</div>
```

Here is the inspected html when there is not an error.

```
<mat-form-field _ngcontent-uiy-c122="" class="mat-form-field ng-tns-c109-0 mat-primary mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-has-label mat-form-field-hide-placeholder mat-form-field-should-float ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid">

<div class="mat-form-field-wrapper ng-tns-c109-0">

    <div class="mat-form-field-flex ng-tns-c109-0"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"}--><!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"}-->
        
        <div class="mat-form-field-infix ng-tns-c109-0">

            <input _ngcontent-uiy-c122="" name="email" formcontrolname="email" matinput="" type="email" autocomplete="off" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c109-0 cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid" ng-reflect-type="email" ng-reflect-placeholder="Email" ng-reflect-name="email" id="mat-input-0" data-placeholder="Email" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false">

            <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper ng-tns-c109-0">

                <label class="mat-form-field-label ng-tns-c109-0 ng-star-inserted" ng-reflect-disabled="true" id="mat-form-field-label-1" ng-reflect-ng-switch="false" for="mat-input-0" aria-owns="mat-input-0">

                <span class="ng-tns-c109-0 ng-star-inserted">Email

                </span>

                <!--ng-container--><!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "false"}--><!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "true"}--><!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"}--></label><!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"}-->
            
            </span>

        </div><!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "0"}-->

    </div>

    <div class="mat-form-field-underline ng-tns-c109-0 ng-star-inserted">

        <span class="mat-form-field-ripple ng-tns-c109-0"></span>

    </div><!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"}-->

    <div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper ng-tns-c109-0" ng-reflect-ng-switch="hint"><!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "error"}-->

        <div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper ng-tns-c109-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transitionMessages ng-star-inserted" style="opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0%);"><!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": ""}-->

            <div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer ng-tns-c109-0">

            </div>

        </div><!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "hint"}-->

    </div>

</div>
```

My updated test which results in an error:

```
describe('email control set to valid email', () => {
      it('should not result in email warning', async () => {
        component.form.get('email').setValue('flo@gmail.com');
        fixture.detectChanges();
        await fixture.whenStable();
        expect(fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('#email-warning')).length).toBe(0);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Just a thought, the spec tests are supposed to be for unit testing and what you are trying to test is actually, that the lib you included for your form fields works as expected. Instead of trying to test that some styles are there or not, I would rather mock material ui - because you can be sure that they've tested their components exhaustively - and test, that the child of the mat-form-field contains your error with the right message.

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig - good point. I have other .spec tests to prove that the correct validators are on their corresponding controls. So, I could leave it at that. This test would really make me feel better though. It would prove that the error is really showing up at what I believe is the correct time. I could rely on Material, but  this is such an easy test to add. I'd like to add it here in the spec if it's possible. PS- I'm checking if the error is showing up, not it's style. Well, it could be considered a style.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are some asynchronous operations you have to wait for before doing assertions.

Try this:

```
describe('email control set to invalid email', () => {
      it('should result in email warning', async() => {
        component.form.get('email').setValue('flo.com');
        fixture.detectChanges();
        await fixture.whenStable(); // wait for promises to complete before asserting
        expect(de.queryAll(By.css('#email-warning')).length).toBe(1);
      });
describe('email control set to invalid email', () => {
      it('should result in email warning', async() => {
        component.form.get('email').setValue('flo@gmail.com');
        fixture.detectChanges(); // wait for promises to complete before asserting
        expect(de.queryAll(By.css('#email-warning')).length).toBe(0);
      });
```

If that doesn't work, you can just stay in the TypeScript of things and be assured that the HTML will behave correctly given that the TypeScript is accurate.

```
describe('email control set to invalid email', () => {
      it('should result in email warning', () => {
        component.form.get('email').setValue('flo.com');
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.form.controls['email'].hasError('email')).toBeTruthy();
      });
describe('email control set to invalid email', () => {
      it('should result in email warning', () => {
        component.form.get('email').setValue('flo@gmail.com');
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.form.controls['email'].hasError('email')).toBeFalsy();
      });
```

EDIT

It seems `de` is the old reference before the `fixture.detectChanges`, I am thinking you need a new reference.

```
describe('email control set to invalid email', () => {
      it('should result in email warning', async() => {
        component.form.get('email').setValue('flo.com');
        fixture.detectChanges();
        await fixture.whenStable(); // wait for promises to complete before asserting
        expect(fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('#email-warning')).length).toBe(1); // grab a new reference by using `fixture.debugElement`
      });
describe('email control set to invalid email', () => {
      it('should result in email warning', async() => {
        component.form.get('email').setValue('flo@gmail.com');
        fixture.detectChanges(); 
        await fixture.whenStable();
        expect(fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('#email-warning')).length).toBe(0); // grab a new reference by using fixture.debugElement
      });
```

Comment: Thanks, but adding the await, did not change the outcome. I have the other spec tests you suggest, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I have edited my answer (added an Edit). Pretty sure you need a new reference to `fixture.debugElement` since it changed. Give it a try.

Comment: I added the new debugElement, but still it doesn't pass. I also moved the async() method to the it line instead of the describe. I've copied my exact test code to the question, so you can see if there's any mistakes I'm making.

Comment: Sorry about the asyncs being in the wrong place. I am not sure then.

Comment: No need for sorry. Thanks for answering back at all. It's a big help just to get confirmation that it should be working.